# EF Core Relationship mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mapping, relationship

In project I can have one `User` that can have many `UserActivites`. In my models I've set up their relationship as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //relationship mapping example
    // delete these attributes and you'll cause a self referenceing loop error
    [JsonIgnore] 
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public List<UserActivity> Activities { get; set; }
}


public class UserActivity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    
    // relationship mapping
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And in my repository class, I'm getting all my user activities this way:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserActivity>> GetAll()
{
    var result = await _context.UserActivities.Include(activity => activity.User).OrderByDescending(x => x.EntryDate).ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

However, when I run my project, the `User` property of `UserActivities` is null. So I checked the Microsoft docs on EF Core relationships and updated my `OnModelCreating` method inside of my context to also do the mapping as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserActivity>().ToTable("UserActivities").Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserActivity>().ToTable("UserActivities").HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany();

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users").Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

However, when I run the project again, my `User` property still isn't populated. I know this isn't a data issue as I have data inside of my `User` table and display that on a separate page.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong/missing with this. So any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the version of your ef core?Actually it works well in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Your tables:

```
  public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            UserActivities = new HashSet<UserActivity>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
     

        [InverseProperty(nameof(UserActivity.User))]
        public virtual ICollection<UserActivity> UserActivities { get; set; }
    }

public partial class UserActivity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Project { get; set; }
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        [InverseProperty("UserActivity")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserActivity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.UserActivities)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_UserActivity_User");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }
```